# VB.net 2008 monitoring mdb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Currently I am writing a code using `VB.net 2008` to display changes happen in an access 2002 database mdb file. The mdb is using by another program for input and i have no access to that program source code.Currently I am using timer function in my program to get latest data from mdb file. Is there any other solution can use to monitoring the database for any changes on table data.

Thanks for any tips and help.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?  does it work?

Comment: Have you looked at the .NET FileSystemWatcher Class?

Comment: If the database was designed with timestamp fields in the tables, you could look at those values. If not, all you can do is take a copy of the data then compare later for changes. How frequently do you need to check for changes/additions?

Comment: Now my timer is running at 2sec to refill the data and it was working fine. FileSystemWatcher class can know mdb file changes?

Comment: `Now my timer is running at 2sec` By using a FileSystemWatcher, you can get rid of your timer. `FileSystemWatcher class can know mdb file changes?` Every change in the folder structure is monitored (file added, deleted, changed, ...). But it's monitoring the **file system**, not the file **contents**.